# How to cast Object to boolean?

Tags: java, casting, primitive

How can I cast a Java object into a boolean primitive

I tried like below but it doesn't work

```
boolean di = new Boolean(someObject).booleanValue();
```

> The constructor Boolean(Object) is undefined

Please advise.

Answer (score 153, accepted):

If the object is *actually* a `Boolean` instance, then just cast it:

```
boolean di = (Boolean) someObject;
```

The explicit cast will do the conversion to `Boolean`, and then there's the auto-unboxing to the primitive value. Or you can do that explicitly:

```
boolean di = ((Boolean) someObject).booleanValue();
```

If `someObject` doesn't refer to a Boolean value though, what do you want the code to do?

Comment: No its not a Boolean instance but has value as true or false

Comment: I'm curious about what type is the variable... :)

Comment: Assuming true / false are Strings you could use: boolean b = Boolean.parseBoolean(String.valueOf(someObject));  Be aware that this will return false for any String value other than "true" (case insensitive) and hence will return false if someObject is null.

Comment: @Jon Answer for the question you asked in last line, We can use `instanceOf` method before casting it to Boolean.This will not give the cast exception.

Comment: @vikiiii: I'm aware of instanceof, but that's a matter of *how* we can check it - that doesn't answer the question I asked, which is the desired *behaviour*.

Comment: @Jon If someObject doesn't refer to a Boolean value though, Lets say be a String .Ex: "true" . Then I will like to parse that String as a boolean and I will use parseBoolean method to convert the string to Boolean. Does that answers your question? If not then please answer back and let me know.

Comment: @vikiiii: Well, it answers part of it. It doesn't answer what you'd want to happen if the value actually referred to an Integer though. Or a Button. Or a FileInputStream. And of course I was asking the OP...

Answer (score 38):

Assuming that yourObject.toString() returns "true" or "false", you can try

```
boolean b = Boolean.valueOf(yourObject.toString())
```

Comment: Have trouble understanding why toString() is required. If it's not a string then it's just an object ?

Comment: because yourObject is an instance of type Object and the valueOf method accepts a String.

Comment: This should probably be `Boolean.parseBoolean` to avoid boxing and unboxing a `Boolean`.

Answer (score -2):

use the conditional operator "?" like this below:

```
int a = 1;   //in case you want to type 1 or 0 values in the constructor call 
Boolean b;   //class var.
b=(a>0?true:false);   //set it in the constructor body
```

Comment: Yes.   But this is not doing what the OP asked.  1)  `int` is not an object type, and certainly not an *arbitrary* object type, 2) this is not a cast.  The real problem is that the original question didn't make sense, and the OP never bothered to clarify it.

Comment: not the real issue