# Cannot cast from Object to boolean

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, session-variables

**This is the error I am receiving,**

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to compile class for JSP: 

    An error occurred at line: 13 in the jsp file: /index.jsp
    Cannot cast from Object to boolean
```

This is my code:

**Controller Servlet**

```
if(authentication.verifyCredentials(request.getParameter("username"), 
   request.getParameter("password")))
{
        session.setAttribute("username", request.getParameter("username"));
        session.setAttribute("loggedIn", true);
        dispatcher.forward(request, response);   
}
```

*I also tried this,*

```
session.setAttribute("loggedIn", new Boolean(true));
```

**JSP**

```
<% 
    if(session.getAttribute("loggedIn") != null)
    {
        if(((boolean)session.getAttribute("loggedIn")))
        {
            response.sendRedirect("Controller"); 
        }
    }   
%>
```

*Yes I researched and also saw the previous stackoverflow [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2206598/how-to-cast-object-to-boolean); however I still cannot resolve my problem. 
Please assist.*

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Try casting it to `Boolean` (nullable) instead of `boolean` in the JSP:

```
if(((Boolean)session.getAttribute("loggedIn")))
{
    response.sendRedirect("Controller"); 
}
```

Comment: Remember, all the lowercase types are built-in primitive types not extending `Object`. If you want to use them with references, you need to use the uppercase versions, which are "boxed" types.

Comment: Thank you for handy tip! Onward I can't forget 'Boolean' :)

Answer (score 8):

try with

```
   if(((Boolean)session.getAttribute("loggedIn")))
```

instead of:

```
   if(((boolean)session.getAttribute("loggedIn")))
```

attribute has to be taken as `Boolean`, not as primitive type