# Python assignment with or

Tags: java, python, jython

I've seen some code similar to:

```
nodeIds = Framework.getDataAsList(key) or []
```

What would be a full fragment of code it translates to? Is the function output being checked for `False` or for `None` outcome? Is there some similar Java syntax for this?

Comment: you need to translate this code in java?

Comment: @ZagorulkinDmitry - Yes, I've edited it in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there is pseudocode:

```
def nonZero(var):
   if isinstance(var,collection): 
     if len(collection) == 0 : return False
     else: return True
   if isinstance(var, number):
     if number == 0 : return False
     else: return True
   if isinstance(var, boolean): return var
   if isinstance(var, NoneType): return False
   if hasattr(var,'__nonzero__'): return var.__nonzero__()


nodeIds = Framework.getDataAsList(key)
if not nonZero(nodeIds) : nodeIds = []
```

Comment: Looks good! But as stated by @Hamish, the original syntax executes `Framework.getDataAsList()` twice, isn't it?

Answer (score 6):

`or` shortcircuits. It the expression on the left is "True" evaluates to that, otherwise it evaluates to the expression on the right (even if it is "False")

If the expression on the left is "True" the expression on the right will not even be evaluated. This is important if it has side-effects

"True" means that `bool(expression) == True`
"False" means that `bool(expression) == False`

Answer (score 2):

A longer version (in Python) might be:

```
nodeIds = Framework.getDataAsList(key)
if not nodeIds:
    nodeIds = []
```

Which might translate into Java almost identically:

```
Vector<foo> nodeIds = Framework.getDataAsList(key);
if(nodeIds == null) {
    nodeIds = new Vector<foo>();
}
```

(my Java is pretty rusty though ;)

Certain values in a 'not' expression evaluate to False. You can try this yourself from the interactive Python command line:

```
>>> not 0
... True
>>> not 1
... False
>>> not []
... True
>>> not ()
... True
>>> not True
... False
>>> not False
... True
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that `Framework.getDataAsList(key)` returns the same result for subsequent calls, it is equivalent to:

```
nodeIds = Framework.getDataAsList(key) if Framework.getDataAsList(key) else []
```

And:

```
if Framework.getDataAsList(key):
    nodeIds = Framework.getDataAsList(key)
else:
    nodeIds = []
```

Note, however, that both these examples require two calls to `Framework.getDataAsList(key)` instead of one. So, perhaps more accurately:

```
nodeIds = Framework.getDataAsList(key)
if not nodeIds:
    nodeIds = []
```

Comment: Thanks! Just to ensure - the original statement only calls the function once?

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> 0 or "yes"
'yes'
>>> None or "yes"
'yes'
>>> False or "yes"
'yes'
>>> [] or "yes"
'yes'
>>> "no" or "yes"
'no'
```

so if the function returns any value that is not [`__nonzero__()`](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#object.__nonzero__) then an empty list is assigned. See also [this part of the official tutorial](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-conditions) on the short-circuit behavior of the boolean operators `and` and `or`. See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1452500/1025391) for more on truth value testing of objects in Python.

Note: from Python 3.0 it's [`__bool__()`](http://docs.python.org/release/3.1.5/reference/datamodel.html#object.__bool__) that is being tested.

---

To Java, this could probably translated using the ternary operator:

```
result = Framework.getDataAsList(key);
nodeIds = result ? result : someEmptyList();
```

[Provided the equivalent boolean conversion of your result object](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2206598/1025391)

Answer (score 0):

It is checked for `False`. So if `Framework.getDataAsList(key)` returns `[]`, `{}`, `0`, `""`, `()`, `None`  or any other value that evaluates to `False`, then `[]` will be assigned to `nodeIDs`.

Answer (score 0):

This Python idiom is common and used in assignments much like the ternary operator from other c-like languages.

```
# python
var = value or fallback
```

is equivalent to:

```
/* c-like */
var = value ? value : fallback
```

both are equivalent to the following pseudo-code:

```
if value is true:
    var = value
else:
    var = fallback
```