# Aggregate List from equal objects in multiple Lists

Tags: java

I'm trying to create a `List<Object> aggregated` based on `List<Object> pool1` and `List<Object> pool2`. The main concern here is obviously performance since we have to compare every object in `pool1` to every object in `pool2`. Is `List` necessary the best option?

Bad code version of the above:

```
List<Object> pool1 = new ArrayList<>();
List<Object> pool2 = new ArrayList<>();
List<Object> matchingObjects = new ArrayList<Object>();
for (Object p1 : pool1) {
    for (Object p2 : pool2) {
        if (p1.equals(p2)) {
            matchingObjects.add(p1);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Use Sets. retainAll would do the work for you.

Comment: `list1.retainAll(list2)` will work I think

Comment: Might work, but is not equivalent to the code posted in the question. `retainAll()` will modify `list1`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`retainAll` will give a `common` elements between two lists

```
  pool1.retainAll(pool2);
  //pool1 contains elements common between two lists
```

if you want a saparate list of common elements than follow below process

```
List<Object> matchingObjects =  (ArrayList<Object>)pool1.clone();
matchingObjects.retainAll(pool2); // now matchingObjects will contain all the common elements
```

Comment: I get `incompatible types: boolean cannot be converted to List<Object>`?

Comment: @Noobcanon change to `List<Boolean>` from `List<Object>` or use [Link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2206604/2749470)

Comment: That's bad advice `retainAll()` returns a boolean, _not_ a new list.

Comment: @Noobcanon what kind of object contained in your both lists is it boolean types than change it from <object> to <Boolean>

Comment: @BhargavModi you have edited the answer, your first version was clearly wrong

Comment: @ci_ ya thats why I edited my answer after your guidance

Comment: This will add all objects to `matchingObjects`, not all equal objects, no?

Comment: @Noobcanon matchingObjects after retainAll() will contain list of all common objects

Comment: @Noobcanon if it helped atleast upvote it and mark it as correct :)