# Casting to arbitrary non-generic return type at runtime, C#

Tags: c#, generics, reflection, casting, return-type

I'm trying to make a user-friendly debug framework where users can create more debug variables as easily as possible.

I need to cast an object to the return type of my property/method (bool, int, whatever), *without* knowing what that return type is.

tldr: How can I return a non-generic type (in this example bool) from

```
public bool MyGetSetProperty {
    get {
        object obj = new object();
        return (bool)obj;
    }
}
```

WITHOUT specifying "return (bool)"? So something like

```
return (GenericThingHereThatPassesAsBool)obj;
```

or

```
return obj as MyGetSetPropertyReturnType;
```

### ----------

Detail:

I want users to be able to create new properties in this class as easily as possible - basically copying+pasting the whole code block below, and only replacing "SerializeAll" with their variable name, and the type declaration "bool" with the type they want on the field/property declarations.

In my getter, I have a couple separate checks to see if the entire debug system is enabled. If not, it returns a default value for the given variable.

```
[Tooltip ("Serialize ALL XML output fields?"), SerializeField]
private bool debugSerializeAll = false;

/// <summary>
/// Serialize ALL XML output fields?
/// </summary>
[DebugValue, DebugDefault (true)]
public bool SerializeAll {

    get {
        if (!classEnabled || !debug.debugEnabled)
            return (bool)GetDefaultValue (MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod ());
        return debugSerializeAll;
    }

    set { debugSerializeAll = value; }

}
```

The thing is, I can't return "default" because the default value can be overridden - see the "DebugDefault" attribute where the "default" value for this bool is actually "true", at least as far as my debug system is concerned. The method "GetDefaultValue" accommodates for that, and it returns an **object** that could be a string, int, bool, anything.

I'm already doing funky reflection stuff to access the MethodInfo, PropertyInfo, etc of the getter and property SerializeAll. I just can't figure out how to **not** have to also specify the (bool) cast on the return. Again, the goal is as little human editing as possible.

Thank you!

Comment: If performance is of no concern to you, you can use the `MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().ReturnType` and then invoke whatever funky conversion mechanism you prefer -- `Convert.ChangeType` is one, if you want more predictability instantiating a delegate with `Expression.Convert` is another. The shortest code would be casting it to `dynamic`, and then have the compiler take care of the rest. Again, none of these approaches are fast in any way compared to actually performing the correct conversion at compile time.

Comment: Also, consider making this code available as a [code snippet](https://learn.microsoft.com/visualstudio/ide/code-snippets) instead of making users actually copy and paste code. Snippets allow flexible replacement of things that only have to be typed once, so then it'd be no problem that `bool` occurs twice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to do this with a cast to `dynamic`.

```
        return (dynamic)GetDefaultValue (MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod ());
```

Bear in mind that the compiler isn't actually making this into a cast to `bool`. Rather, this makes the compiler ignore compile-time type-safety, and instead the program will use reflection at runtime to figure out the best way to take the value returned from GetDefaultValue and turn it into what it needs to be.

> I want users to be able to create new properties in this class as easily as possible...

This is a good principle.

> ... basically copying+pasting the whole code block below, and only replacing "SerializeAll" with their variable name, and the type declaration "bool" with the type they want on the field/property declarations.

That totally breaks the principle you just mentioned, and results in a bunch of boilerplate code and other code smells.

In theory, you could probably create a Fody Weaver or something to add this boilerplate code upon compilation. But that's probably more work than it's worth.

I would hazard a guess that this is an "XY Problem", where you're asking how to achieve the solution that you've imagined, rather than asking how to solve the problem you're actually facing.

Why should every property in your class return a completely different value if certain private fields are set a certain way? This sounds like a big Separation of Concerns problem, where you're tasking your class with doing two completely different things. I strongly suggest you find another way to solve the problem you're trying to solve. For example, when code tries to get an instance of your class, it could go through a method that checks the `classEnabled` and `debug.debugEnabled` concepts (which probably belong in a different class), and returns an instance with the properties all set to their defaults.

Comment: SUPER belated (wow this comment is juuuuust barely pre-covid lol) but thank you so much! This answer has helped me like three times since you've posted it :)

Answer (score 0):

Please Link click here -> [How to cast Object to boolean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2206598/how-to-cast-object-to-boolean)

or

I think you need to study for Generic class

[Check if a class is derived from a generic class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/457676/check-if-a-class-is-derived-from-a-generic-class)